# How to troubleshoot / investigate an error during GitLab pages upload?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I run my pages job and it passes, however with the following message at the end

```
Uploading artifacts...
WARNING: public: no matching files
Uploading artifacts to coordinator... ok
Job succeeded
```

The website appears not to be served. All the build steps succeeded without error. I tried the build locally on my machine and verified it is correct. The website's entry point is `index.html` (I guess that's correct?).

How can I troubleshoot this problem? It would be nice if I could do the job "manually" so I could check a few things after the files are built on the CI machine. Like that I don't have to commit+push a new `.gitlab-ci.yml` all the time for checking / trying things.

Any suggestions are highly appreciated! Thanks!

P.S.: I build the website using Sphinx if that is of importance.

## Edit - Some details

I build the documentation via Sphinx' Makefile (which is part of my documentation's source). Sphinx confirms me that the files are placed in `build/html` (I confirmed this on my local machine) and I copy them to the public folder. Here's the corresponding excerpt of my `ci.yaml`:

```
- make html
- mkdir ~/.public
- cp -r build/html/* ~/.public/
- cd
- mv .public public
```

I don't know what information from Sphinx' `conf.py` could be interesting for that case, I've scanned through it and it doesn't seem to be corrupted (also the local build works).

As an output I obtain an `index.html` + several other HTML files which are linked from `index.html`. This all gets placed in `~/public`.

I would really appreciate to be able to do those build steps manually on the build server as I could take a look at the build files then and maybe figure what's wrong. I didn't find any documentation that this was possible however I also don't think that's really the idea behind CI. Right now I'm not sure how I should tackle this problem as it builds fine on my machine and on the other hand I can't access the build server directly.

## Edit 2

I verified with

```
ls -al ~/public
```

in my `ci.yaml` file the generated files and they are all at the correct place. Especially:

```
$ ls -al ~/public
[...]
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  5621 Apr 13 23:31 index.html
[...]
```

So it seems that GitLab pages is expecting something else than / something in addition to `index.html`?? I've run the Jekyll example from the their examples pages repository and this worked fine having an `index.html`. But maybe Jekyll produces some more files during the build process.

Comment: It looks like you've told it that the artifacts are places in the `public` folder, but that folder doesn't exist. Can't tell more than that without your `.gitlab-ci.yml` and config file for Sphinx..

Comment: @fredrik I added some details to the question. I'm almost certain that the files are correctly placed in the `public` folder however I can't confirm that because I don't have direct access to the build machine. However I guess that's the purpose of CI so I'm not sure if there's a way to perform those steps manually and have a look at the build files?

Comment: You can browse/download the artifacts from a built, so that you can see what's been created. ;) a link to your repo would help us to help you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/user/project/pages/introduction.html?&_ga=1.95220571.63798462.1491939718#explore-the-contents-of-gitlab-ci-yml) and [this tutorial](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/pages/getting_started_part_four.html#the-public-directory) GitLab pages will only consider a folder named `public` which resides *inside the project's directory*. That is the HTML content should go to `~/projectname/public` instead of `~/public`.

Comment: `~/public` in a docker image, as root, is actually `/root/public` :] So we must put the `public/` directory at the first level.

Answer (score 0):

I think I got eaten by this problem. Actually `~/public` in a docker image, where we are connected as root… is `/root/public` :) and not what gitlab pages expects.

You should try

```
mv build/html public
```